# Set AWS Route53 endpoint as unhealthy due to latency?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

We already set endpoint records as unhealthy using route 53 health checks. After they fail X consecutive failures they go into ALARM state and get marked as unhealthy.

Now that route 53 has added latency graphs for health checks, has anyone figured out how to set an endpoint as unhealthy if the latency falls below a certain threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried this myself but you could try doing it the following.

- create a health check with latency enabled
- create alarm based on the latency metric
- create a health check that uses the status of your latency metric alarm
- create a calculated health check with #1 and #3.

Use the calculated health check in your rrset.

Comment: Was able to use Alarm target: TCP connection time and then set Fulfill condition: Average. Looks like I need to recreate all the health checks with latency enabled to make this change across the board. Thanks!